# Why can't I get the proper y position in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, position

When I run the function `spin()` for the first time, it works. I get the y coordinate of the image called `num`, which is 470. In every run that follows, it stays 470, even though you can see the image move!

```
<p id="demo">Click the button to display the y position.</p>
<div style="position:absolute; top:450px; width:300px; height:140px; overflow:hidden; background-color:black;">
    <div style="position:relative; top:20px; left:30px; width:80px; height:100px; overflow:hidden; background-color:white;">
        <img id="numbers" src="numbers.png" style="position: absolute; left: 8px;">
    </div>
    <button id="spinButton" style="position: relative; left: 200px; width: 80px;" onclick="spin();">SPIN</button>
</div>
```

```
var num = document.getElementById("numbers");
var spn_btn = document.getElementById("spinButton");

function spin() {
    //generate a random offset value divisible by 100
    var newNumber = (randomNumber() * 100) + 300;

    //Debug
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = num.y;

    TweenMax.to(num, 2, {
        y: -newNumber
    });
}

function randomNumber() {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    return rand;
}
```

<sub>(Uses [TweetMax](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js))</sub>

Comment: Please, remove a few newlines! We can't see more than 4 lines of your code at once.

Comment: Psst… you don’t have to reserve space for future code

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is with this line:

```
TweenMax.to(num, 2, {y:-newNumber});
```

I'm not familiar with this library so I don't know if it's doing what it's supposed to. Also I don't see the image popping up on my screen anywhere. Can you expand on what the desired functionality is?

Comment: the image won't pop becouse it's stored in my computer :)
it's supposed to emulate a slot machine. and the image is a strip of numbers, having only one number located inside a viewing window at each given moment.
i am trying to read the y position of the image as it's moving upwards so it seems like the numbers inside the window are changing

Comment: @user2714195 can you host the image somewhere so I can test further?